# Parsley.js skip validation on submit?

Tags: javascript, parsley.js

When I try to submit a form, either via an input[type=submit] or by calling form.submit(), Parsley validates the form and cancels the submission if invalid. Is there any way I can skip that validation since I'm manually calling validate on sections of my form?

Specifically what I'm trying to achieve is submitting partial versions of the form, so I validate a group and  only that portion is sent to the server (even if the rest of the form is still not valid).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I you want to cancel Parsley default validation on submit event, you'll have to remove the `submit.Parsley` binded event on your form.

Doing a `$('#yourform').off('submit.Parsley');` should solve your issue.

Best

Edit: For Parsley2, since events names have changed, it should be `$('#yourform').off('form:validate');`

Comment: If you have time to add this to the Parsley docs, that would be handy.  I have a scenario where we have a "Save Basket" button on the form, and not till I found this could I find a way to disable validation w/o destroying the Parsley instance wholly, to enable people to submit the form to Save the cart.  But the lib is great, thank you!

Comment: Should perhaps have used a commit-specific link there, it longer goes anywhere useful.

Comment: @aptwebapps you're right. I updated the answer accordingly to the documentation, not tested though..

Comment: @guillaumepotier No, I meant the github link just goes to master and it looks like the line number no longer points to where you want it to.

Comment: Your `$('#yourform').off('form:validate');` doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to skip single element just use :

```
data-parsley-excluded
```

> Form fields that won't be validated by Parsley. For example, if you
>   want to add disabled and hidden fields to the existing list, use:
>   data-parsley-excluded="input[type=button], input[type=submit],
>   input[type=reset], input[type=hidden], [disabled], :hidden"

but if you want to validate a specific groupd then use:

```
data-parsley-group
```

> Assign a group to a field for specific group validation. eg:
>   data-parsley-group="signup". This way, you could only validate a
>   portion of a form and not all the fields.

source :

http://parsleyjs.org/doc/index.html#psly-usage-form

Comment: Yeah, I'm using both things you mention. But regardless of that, Parsley still re-validates the whole form when trying to submit it. That's what I want to skip, because I have already called validation for each group before.

Comment: what do you mean by re validate ?

Comment: It runs validation again, and form submission is cancelled.

Comment: @DanielBang can you please fiddle it , or send full code , i will be glad to help once i get the problem clearly.

Comment: Thanks. I've gone directly to the code and there's currently no way to skip validation on submit.

Answer (score 0):

When running the submit in JS you can do:

`$('#yourform').parsley().destroy();`

So with jQuery in code, it could look like this:

```
var $myForm = $('#yourform');

$("#submit-button").on('click',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  
  $myForm.parsley().destroy();
  $myForm.submit();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As I answered here, adding `formnovalidate` to the button seems to work
https://stackoverflow.com/a/74746624/1148163