# Parsley: How to prevent validation when pressing buttons other than submit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsley.js

Thank you for any help.

I am trying to use Parsley for Form Validation. My form has one submit button and some other buttons to dynamically add inputs to the form. But when I press these other buttons, form validation is carried out. But I am not submitting any form.

How to prevent form validation from happening when I press other buttons than submit button?

Sorry, I dont know how to JS Fiddle. My code is like the following:

```
<form method="post" action="confirm" data-parsley-validate>
    <input id="brand" data-parsley-trigger="submit" required />
    <button id="addQuantity">Add</button>
    <input type="number" required data-parsley-trigger="submit" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

When I press Add, the form is validated. How should I prevent this?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle with a sample of the code you have ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tag button which was introduced in HTML5 is equivalent to input type="submit"  hence when you press add it will automatically fire submit action.  What you can do is replace the tag to input type="button" or you can prevent the default action in jquery like this

```
 <script> 
   $('#addQuantity').click(function(event)
    {
       event.preventDefault();
       //do your action goes below
    });
 </script>
```

Comment: This shows the fine print of the API is more important. LOL

Answer (score 0):

I found adding `formnovalidate` to the button skipped form validation for the form only when clicking that button.